# Change in the objective of Tip Selection Algorithm post-Coordicide

Tags: tip-selection

The paper on the Coordicide states- *"Although the Tip Selection is not part of the conflict resolution in our current approach to the Coordicide, it still plays many important roles in the Tangle. It keeps the Tangle growing in an scalable and decentralized way."*

How will the relevance of weighted random walk TSAs change post Coordicide?